# Script to pin Office shortcuts to Windows 8 Start

Tags: windows-8, vbscript

I need to be able to pin the MS Office 2013 shortcuts on the Windows 8 Start menu. I have used this [script](http://www.labnol.org/software/shutdown-restart-in-windows-8/20989/) to pin log off button and it works great. I've modified it in attempts to pin Excel 2013 and it does not work.

```
    '
' This script will create shortcuts in the Start Menu
'
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strStartMenu = WshShell.SpecialFolders("StartMenu")

set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strStartMenu & "\Excel.lnk")
oShellLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE"
oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1
oShellLink.IconLocation = "%ProgramFiles% (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\XLICONS.EXE"
oShellLink.Description = "Microsoft Excel 2013"
oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15"
oShellLink.Save
Set oShellLink = Nothing

Wscript.Echo "Created Icons"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No error, it does copy the Excel.lnk file to the %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu but it doesn't pin the shortcut. It does for the log off icon in the script that I linked to.